# creating a form and populating it with values in database in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to make a form that is populated with values in database

```
class Venue(models.Model):
venue_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
rent = models.IntegerField()
parking_area = models.IntegerField()
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want the form to show all the field present here

Comment: Please read the documentation on [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/) and come back if you have a *specific* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, **Input**

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from youapp.models import Venue

class VenueForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
```

views.py

```
from youapp.forms import VenueForm

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def contact(request):
    form = VenueForm()
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        # VenueForm was defined in the the previous section
        form = VenueForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST


    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

template.html

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/

**2.Output**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
```

see here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: Questioner must accept the answer which is more relevant.

Comment: first off all you just the opposite  i asked for. I want to print the data present in the database in html inside form so that when i select the venue i get the information of which venue was selected

Comment: generic view, need this?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform